# Как сделать кликабельный интерфейс в консольном приложении python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Какие в питоне есть библиотеки с помощью которых можно сделать интерфейс подобный FAR Manager ?
Подскажите где что искать, в гугле ничего толкового найти не смог.

Comment: сначала подумал: чо заа... А потом вспомнил Vim

Comment: Давно пробовал делать на urwid (и twisted) терминальный сервер с виджетами, до продакшна не дошло. Но помню, чем-то он мне понравился больше ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл, npyscreen и ещё кажется ncurses.